# How to make persistent storage for filter driver?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, kernel, filter-driver

I am trying to save certain data like some bitmap by using the structure as

```
typedef struct _BITMAPDATA
{
    CHAR* bitmapData;
    ULONG bitmapSize;
}BITMAPDATA,*PBITMAPDATA;
```

I have created these bitmap through filter driver, bitmaps is working fine but,**how can i store that bitmap in an persistent storage like hard disk.** So that whenever system gets crashed or shutdown accidently, driver must store all the bitmaps created in an persistent storage and when system restart, it will reload them.

Answer (score 1):

If the system crashes or unexpectedly shuts down, you can't be sure of anything, including the saving of your data. You can attempt to save the data but it's not guaranteed to succeed. You can use the Kernel file handling APIs, such as [ZwWriteFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You can register a [bug check callback routine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566401%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that will write your data to a file when bug check (i.e. system crash) occurs but like said before - it's not guaranteed to succeed due to the nature of event - the occurred error may prevent the file writing, for example.